# "Unable to load the requested class" error only on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, remote-server

I've an **CodeIgniter** application and **it works** fine on my **local laptop** (Windows 7). 
I have uploaded the files to the **remote server** and now it **gives an error** `Unable to load the requested class: itemblocklibrary`.

The code where the library is loaded:

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->load->helper('member_area_helper'); // works
$ci->load->library('itemBlockLibrary'); // dies here
```

The file is located on the remote server at: `/www/case/project/application/libraries/itemBlockLibrary.php`

I tried:

```
echo 'Have you seen ' . APPPATH . 'libraries/itemBlockLibrary.php? <br/>';
echo (file_exists(APPPATH . 'libraries/itemBlockLibrary.php') ? 'Yes sir, it does exists!' : 'No sir, can\'t find it');
```

Output:

```
Have you seen application/libraries/itemBlockLibrary.php? 
Yes sir, it does exists!
```

And:

- using lower case `$ci->load->library('itemblocklibrary');` -> same error
- loading another library -> same error
- tripple check file existents (FTP) -> is there
- checked folder and file permissions. (folder: 755, files: 644; same as helpers folder)

Can someone help me keeping my hair? ;)

Comment: Do other links and internal routing work? Sounds almost like an htaccess issue.

Comment: @RickCalder Just tried it, I can navigate some pages/routes. Also checked the code of the working pages and saw that it only uses the build in libraries and none custom..

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having exactly the same issue. :s

Comment: @m0dE I'm sorry but this is too long ago for me to remember, so can't help you..

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your server is some flavor of Linux and you encountering case sensitivity. Your file uses a camel case name `itemBlockLibrary.php` and is being converted to all lower case and upper case first letter to find a matching file in the directory by the `CI_Loader` class.

From the Loader class, `_ci_load_class` function:

```
// We'll test for both lowercase and capitalized versions of the file name
foreach (array(ucfirst($class), strtolower($class)) as $class)
```

Change your file name to use the CI convention of

- File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php
- Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
- Class names and file names must match.

Take a look at the documentation for [custom library classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

In your case, you'll want to name your file as `MY_itemblocklibrary.php` (or what ever prefix you set in your config file) and then load it as:

```
$this->load->library('MY_itemblocklibrary');
```

Comment: When I change the class name and filename to all lowercase, then it still not working. When I add the `MY_` before the filename and classname, then it works. But then I have to rewrite the a lot in the application because `$this->itemblocklibrary->method()` lines won't work anymore. So that's more an work-around. The real problem is that it wont want to load the files in the folder libaries when they are named without `MY_`.

Comment: You have two options. You could try setting the `$config['subclass_prefix']` to `''` an empty string; the documentation states this prefix is to allow you to extend native libraries, but since you are creating your own class just try removing it. Or, you can pass in an object alias as the third argument to the loader class: `$this->load->library('MY_itemblocklibrary',array(),'itemBlockLibrary');`